# How to use access token with PHP SDK and retrieve user_activities parameter using fql?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I was wondering how to use access token obtained by the getAccessToken() in PHP SDK
Following is my code snippet trying to display user email id as well as user activities :
When I run this code emAIL AND USER ACTIVITIES are blank how do I fix this?

```
      <?php



    require '/home/vespanve/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '39653698mmmmm448',
      'secret' => 'd7681299469mmmmmmmmmmmmm',
    ));

    $config = array(
        'appId' => '39653698mmmmm448',
        'secret' => 'd7681299469mmmmmmmmmmmmm',
      );

      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

    ?>
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>

      <?
        if($user_id) {

// We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
// If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {

            $fql = 'SELECT name from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
        $fqlmail = 'SELECT email from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
        $fqlact = 'SELECT user_activities from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                                       'query' => $fql,
                                     ));
        $ret_obj2 = $facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                      'access_token' => $cookie['access_token'],
                                      'query' => $fqlmail,
                                     ));
        $ret_obj3 = $facebook->api(array(
                                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                      'access_token' => $cookie['access_token'],
                                      'query' => $fqlact,
                                     ));

            // FQL queries return the results in an array, so we have
            //  to get the user's name from the first element in the array.
            echo '<pre>Name: ' . $ret_obj[0]['name'] . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>Email: ' . $ret_obj2[0]['email'] . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>Activities: ' . $ret_obj3[0]['user_activities'] . '</pre>';
        $facebook->destroySession();



          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

// No user, so print a link for the user to login
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        }
    ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask for extended permissions:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email, user_activities',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

For more info on this you can chek here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

For permissions here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Hey,Email is getting retrieved but when i try to print the user_activities the app doesn't give any output only asks for authentication and stops working.